# Detect Modifiers Key from external DragAndDrop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I seem to be unable to detect any ModifiersKey using `Keyboard.Modifiers` when the DragAndDrop source is external to my own application.

Using a simple handler like

```
private void dragNdrop_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Keyboard.Modifiers);
}
```

Works like a charm when it comes to my own method

```
private void onClick_Button(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    DataObject dragData = new DataObject(DataFormats.StringFormat, btn.Tag);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dragData, DragDropEffects.Link);
}
```

But when dragging an item from any explorer, `Keyboard.Modifiers` only ever show `None`.

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `e.AllowedEffects` and `e.KeyStates`.